# how can I fix an oledbexception error that happens when I try to open connection to the database

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access, webforms, oledbconnection

I am trying to open a connection between a webform and an Access database, however, the oledb connection won't open and when I run the program it stops on the con.open() and gives me this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Could not use ''; file already in use.

this is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Log_in : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Database1.mdb");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Btn_log_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID user, password FROM users WHERE password='itamar'";
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        if (rows == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Log_in.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also appears to be an error in the SQL string. Looks like need a comma between ID and user. Will multiple users use that same password?

Comment: I have seen examples with and without doubled \. Try single \.

Comment: @June7 In C#, a \ starts a character escape sequence. A second \ adds a single escaped \ to the string (much like doubling quotes in VBA. With a single \ it won't compile.

Comment: @OP That error is pretty explicit: the database is already in use (another program has access to it). Using Access with ASP.Net is explicitly not supported by Microsoft. While you might be able to work around this error, don't. Use SQL Server (express edition if you don't want to buy a license) or another RDBMS instead. See the details [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920) for example.